# Web-page scaling for mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Dealing with a problem that my web-page is not scaled correctly in mobile browser windows, especially it ignores all the `float:left` properties, and I assume, one of the reason is the declaration of width/height the way I did. Any advice on fixing css the mobile-friendly way?

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#header_chat {
    height: 100%;
}

#header_logo_menu {
    background-color: #fedc3d;
    width: 700px;
    height: 171px;
    float:left;
    border-top: 5px solid #01abaa;
    border-left: 5px solid #01abaa;
}

#header_right_menu {
    height: 171px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #01abaa;
    border-top: 5px solid #fedc3d;
    border-right: 5px solid #fedc3d;
}

#chat_big {
    height: 100%;
}

#chat_messages {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    height: 570px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#inner_messages {
    width: 700px;
    height: 570px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #fedc3d;
    color: #000000;
    border: 5px solid #01abaa;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: initial;
}

#user_list {
    height: 560px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #01abaa;
    border: 5px solid #fedc3d;
}

#chat_text {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid #01abaa;
    font-size: large;
    resize: none;
}

#send_message_button {
    width:20%;
    height: 68.5px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#send_message_button:hover {
    border: 5px solid #01abaa;
    background-color: #fedc3d; 
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none; 
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#profile_button {
    width: 15%;
    height: 68.5px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#profile_button:hover {
    border: 5px solid #01abaa;
    background-color: #fedc3d; 
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none; 
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#log_out_button {
    width:13.85%;
    height: 68.5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#log_out_button:hover {
    border: 5px solid #01abaa;
    background-color: #fedc3d; 
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none; 
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link href="../styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0'>
            <title>Chat App Home</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header_chat">
                <div id="header_logo_menu">    
                </div>
                <div id="header_right_menu">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="chat_big">
                <div id="chat_messages">
                    <div id="inner_messages">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id = "user_list">
                    <div id="users_online">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                <textarea id = "chat_text" name = "chat_text"></textarea>
                <input type = "button" id = "send_message_button" value = "Send Message"/>
                <input type = "button" id = "profile_button" value = "My Profile"/>
                <input type = "button" id = "log_out_button" value = "Log Out"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: correctly scaled meaning?What is your expected results ?

Comment: Well, first thing I expect is to see all div blocks floating the way they do in non-mobile version, which does not look the same when browsing on mobile. Second thing is that I am not sure if declaration of width/height is correct for mobile usage, and if any changes can be applied this way.

Comment: edit your question and add your css

Comment: mlegg, I have edited question (added code snippet of html/css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general it's better to use percentage values combined with `max-width` values for mobile devices, i.e. in media queries, for example like this

```
.my_div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
}
```

This will fill the while width on screens up to 480px and stay at 480px width for screens above 480px width.

You can put rules of this kind into media queries (for example `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)`) and ADD them to your stylesheet. So on desktop you'll have the rules you have now, and on devices less than 769px wide these additional rules apply.

Your fixed pixel widths are definitely to wide for mobile devices.

Comment: Am I right, that by using this approach I will create a version, that will be friendly for mobile devices browsers (with width up to 480px), but that will not be that good looking on PC browsers?

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I understand the way I should continue developing this thing. Thank you!